# How to center a line in a verbatim LATEX?

Tags: latex

I have the following code:

```
\begin{verbatim}
{app_id:X[X]YY}
\end{verbatim}
```

This verbatim box only contains one line. I simply want to center that only line. How can I do it? `\centerline` doesn't work inside `verbatim`. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Do you actually need a verbatim environment, or would an inline verbatim also do the job?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99940/49683) out!

Comment: Also: [How to center verbatim](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/122195/49683) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorted out thanks to [this source](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/122197/49683):

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{BVerbatim}
{app_id:X[X]YY}
\end{BVerbatim}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image: screenshot of output pdf]

You need the package [`fancyvrb`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fancyvrb) to implement this solution.